One of my Image Targets works in Unity preview but does work in the app? Unity 2022.3.21f1, Mac Pro 2023
On the free membership is there a limit to how many "image targets" we get?
I updated one of my image targets and now it does not work when the app is copied to my iPhone?
I switched the image multiple times with still no luck

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
